# How to load particular texts of text file to particular textboxes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, text-files, streamreader

I have created a project in C# windows form application. I am using .Net framework version 4.0 and Visual studio 2010.
Project contains Save and load File button. And also some textboxes.

I created a text file like this

```
Serial Number = 1
Type Number = 500
Test Engineer = jay
Date = 03/05/2018
Time = 16:17:20 PM
Test1 = 1.00
Test2 = 1.76
.
.
.
Test18 = 4.66
```

Code for Load File button:

```
private void btn_LoadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog fdlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (fdlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new
        System.IO.StreamReader(fdlg.FileName);

        string[] lines = sr.ReadToEnd().Split('\n');
        tb_SerialNo.Text = lines[0];
        tb_TypeNo.Text = lines[1];
        tb_TestEngineer.Text = lines[2];
        tb_Date.Text = lines[3];
        tb_Test1.Text = lines[4];
        tb_Test2.Text = lines[5];
    }  
}
```

When I run above code, I got value in Serial no textbox is `Serial Number = 1` but I want `1`in textbox. Same `Type Number` Tex box `Type Number = 500` but here also I want  `500` in Type number textbox.

Comment: Try using `Split`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you split by new line, `lines[0]` will store `Serial Number = 1`. Here you need to split it again by `=`.

If you try and print values of each element from string array, you will understand what changes you need to do in your code.

```
 private void btn_LoadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog fdlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (fdlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            System.IO.StreamReader sr = new
            System.IO.StreamReader(fdlg.FileName);

            string[] lines = sr.ReadToEnd().Split('\n'); //To make your code more readable, you can use "Environment.NewLine" instead of '\n'
            Console.WriteLine(lines[0]); //Here it will give "Serial Number = 1"
            // you need to store 1 in tb_SerialNo.Text, so split lines[0] with =
           //Have you tried with this.
            string[] splitWithEqualTo = lines[0].Split('=');
            tb_SerialNo.Text = splitWithEqualTo [1];
          //Similar kind of logic you can apply for other text boxes.
        }  
    }
```

---

To fix your issue, you can try with the followings

```
Console.WriteLine(lines[0]); // This will print "Serial Number = 1"
string[] slitLine = lines[0].Split('=');
Console.WriteLine(slitLine[0]); //This will print "Serial Number"
Console.WriteLine(slitLine[1]); //This will print 1, this is what you need to store in tb_SerialNo.Text, right?
```

This is not the solution, but you will understand what changes you need to do in your code.

---

Comment: I updated my answer, to make it easier. Have you tried with my approach? If yes, then what issues you are facing ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void btn_LoadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog fdlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (fdlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            System.IO.StreamReader sr = new
            System.IO.StreamReader(fdlg.FileName);

            string[] lines = sr.ReadToEnd().Split('\n');
            PrintText(tb_SerialNo, lines[0]);
            PrintText(tb_TypeNo , lines[1]);
            PrintText(tb_TestEngineer, lines[2]);
            PrintText(tb_Date, lines[3]);
            PrintText(tb_Test1, lines[4]);
            PrintText(tb_Test2, lines[5]);
        }

    }
    private void PrintText(TextBox control, string line)
    {
        var splitline = line.Split('=');
        control.Text = splitline[1];
    }
```

try this

Comment: Why should he try this?

Comment: @Prasadtelkikar thanks your advice. will keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [string.Split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) or [string.LastIndexOf()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof(v=vs.110).aspx) to extract the part you need from the original string.

For example:

Here, we split the string in two when a `'='` char is found. The extra space is lifted by `Trim()`, which is used to remove white spaces from the leading and trailing parts of a string.

```
tb_Test2.Text = lines[5].Split('=').Last().Trim();
```

or

`LastIndexOf()` finds the symbol specified, starting its search from the end of a string and returns its position (if it finds it, otherwise -1).

[`Substring()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6(v=vs.110).aspx) generates a new string from the supplied one, starting from a position and taking a specified number of characters.
Here, starting from the index returned by `LastIndexOf()` and including all the characters to the end of the string (if you don't specify how many characters it has to take, it takes them all. It's a method overload).

```
tb_Date.Text = lines[3].Substring(lines[3].LastIndexOf("=") + 1).TrimStart();
```

In both cases, the original string remains untouched.

You can also create a new array from the original one, containing only the required parts and then assign the values of the new array:

```
string[] lines2 = lines.Select(s => s.Split('=').Last().Trim()).ToArray();

tb_SerialNo.Text = lines2[0];
tb_TypeNo.Text = lines2[1];
//(...)
```